# How to inverse transform this function, when solving PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve this following PDE problem
$$
\begin{align}\begin{cases} u_{t} = u_{xx} + au_{x}, \;- \infty  < x < \infty , t > 0 \\   \\  u(x,0) = \frac{1}{x^{2}+1}    \end{cases} \end{align}
$$
by using Fourier transform. I'm not experienced with this method, but after some steps, what I get is the solution to the ODE, which is
$$U(\omega,t) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{((ai\omega-\omega^2)t-|\omega|)}.$$
Now I want to inverse transform this function to get the solution of the original problem $u(x,t)$ but I don't know how to follow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a much easier way to solve this problem, if you are interested.

Comment: I was interested in the Fourier transform method, I just need help with that inverse transform. I've tried and I don't see a way to do that. I imagine there has to be some  particular convolution that is the inverse transform of that function... But I'm not seeing it

Comment: What is wrong with just $u=\int_{-\infty}^\infty U e^{i\omega t} d\omega$?

Comment: I need to give an explicit expression for $u(x,t)$ using this method. And when I have to integrate that, I don’t see a way to write it as the inverse transform of a convolution of 2 functions (which I think is the way to solve that, maybe not)

Comment: The result I think is not simple and involves $\operatorname{erf}$.

Comment: And which is the other way to solve this?